# Java nested wildcard generic won't compile

Tags: java, generics, nested, wildcard

I have a problem with bounded nested wildcards in Java generics.

Here's a common case:

```
public void doSomething(Set<? extends Number> set) {}

public void callDoSomething() {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    doSomething(set);
}
```

This is standard Java generics, works fine.

However if the wildcard becomes nested, it no longer works:

```
public void doSomething(Map<String, Set<? extends Number>> map) {}

public void callDoSomething() {
    Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
    doSomething(map);
}
```

This leads to a compiler error.

I've tried a variety of casts and wildcard permutations, but I'm unable to get this working. I don't recall seeing this issue before, and I've worked with generics for years. Am I just too tired and missing something obvious?

Comment: There's an explanation for this in the Java Generics FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the problem is, `doSomething` could be implemented as:

```
public void doSomething(Map<String, Set<? extends Number>> map) {
    Set<Float> set = ...;
    map.put("xyz", set);
}
```

You need to decide what you actually mean.

Probably something like:

```
public void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends Set<? extends Number>> map) {}
```

Comment: Yes, I just independently realized this. I could have sworn I tried that yesterday, but I probably had some other subtle change.

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you:

```
public void doSomething(Map<String, ? extends Set<? extends Number>> map) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make code to work Create HashMap as:

```
Map<String, Set<? extents Number>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<? extents Number>>();
```