# Issue with declaration of Map<String,Class<? extends Serializable>>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, extends, serializable

Java provides me by `<? extends class>` a way of filtering the java classes that you can use to
build in this case the new HashMap, for example:

I can do that:

```
Map<String,? extends Serializable> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

It is correct, because String implements Serializable, so the compiler let me do that.

But when i try to do it:

```
Map<String,GenericClass<? extends Serializable>> map2 = new HashMap<String, GenericClass<String>>();
```

Being the GenericClass as it:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
.
.
.
}
```

The compiler throw an error saying:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,GenericClass<String>> to Map<String,GenericClass<? extends Serializable>>
```

I would like to know, what is happen?

Maybe the compiler cannot detect the extends class being part of a generic type.

Comment: theres a missing > in `new HashMap<String, GenericClass<String>();`

Comment: sorry i pasted it incorrectly, edited

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java nested wildcard generic won't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405866/java-nested-wildcard-generic-wont-compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the following:

```
Map<String, ? extends GenericClass<? extends Serializable>> map2 =
        new HashMap<String, GenericClass<String>>();
```

Nested wildcards are much different from top-level wildcards - only the latter perform [*wildcard capture*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). As a result, `HashMap<String, GenericClass<String>>` is considered inconvertible to `Map<String, GenericClass<? extends Serializable>>`, because `GenericClass<? extends Serializable>` is a concrete type argument (and because generics [aren't covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)).

See this post for further information on nested wildcards: [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu/3547372#3547372)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,? extends Serializable> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

`map1` contains an **unbounded** `V` that only requires an unknown of `Serializable`'s. Hence it cannot find a generified object to bound this to, except for `null`.

```
Map<String,GenericClass<? extends Serializable>> map2 = new HashMap<String, GenericClass<String>>();
```

The `map2` is **bounded** by a type `K` (in this case `String`) and `V` (`Class<? exends Serializable`). That's how the Java compiler sees the bounds.

In essence, you cannot `put` anything in `map1` except a null as you will only see `map1.put(String key, null value) //Compiler is asking WTF here`.
Whereas, `map2` will, essentially "render" as `map2.put(String key, Class<? extends Serializable> value); //Much better...`.

Because of the bound `V` in `map2`, the signature must be the same in its declaration.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.