# Double wildcard parameterization (nested wildcards) with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I am using a method from a third party library ([Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)) which is supposed to find subtypes of the given type and looks like

```
public <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getSubTypesOf(final Class<T> type) {
...
```

When the caller code looks like

```
Class<?> type = ...
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

I am getting a compile error: "`cannot convert from Set<Class<? extends capture#19-of ?>> to Set<Class<?>>`". The following fixes the situation:

```
Class<?> type = ...
Set<?> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ht);
```

so it looks like the only possible remedy for incorrect `Set<Class<? extends ?>>` would be `Set<?>` but not `Set<Class<?>>`. Why is it so?
Thanks for any explanation on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
Set<? extends Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

The problem is that *nested wildcards* don't perform [type capture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). Declaring a `Set<Class<?>>` means "a set of classes of *any type*", while what's being returned is a `Set<Class<? extends capture#19-of ?>>`, which means "a set of classes of any type extending from *some specific unknown type*". In this case, that "specific unknown type" is derived from the type argument to `T`, which is inferred from `type` to be an unbounded wildcard capture (the `?` in `Class<?>`).

For example, pretend that "specific unknown type" is `Number`:

```
Class<Number> type = ...
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

Here, `getSubTypesOf` returns a `Set<Class<? extends Number>>`. That type is *not* assignable to `Set<Class<?>>` because [generic types aren't covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). But, wildcard capture helps us express covariance, allowing types like `Set<? extends Class<?>>`. The caveat is that we can't add anything but `null` to such a set, since we don't know its specific type.

Related posts:

- [Java Generic List<List<? extends Number>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number)
- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)
- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Similar posts:

- [Java: Wildcard Types Mismatch Results in Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736325/java-wildcard-types-mismatch-results-in-compilation-error/19737426#19737426)
- [Issue with declaration of Map<String,Class<? extends Serializable>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723199/issue-with-declaration-of-mapstring-class-extends-serializable/17726399#17726399)
- [Bounded-wildcard related compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907262/bounded-wildcard-related-compiler-error)

Comment: This really works, thank you! Frankly speaking I don't understand for now where `? extends Class<?>` comes from, as it makes me think that we start to deal with extending `Class` which is not what my code is about at all. Ok, will study your overall list of references in more detail :)

Comment: @PavelS Glad to help. When used to express generic bounds, `extends` doesn't necessarily imply a subclass, just a *subtype*. For example `Class<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `Class<?>`. Also note that in this context `Class<?>` would be considered a subtype of itself, so `Set<Class<?>>` would be assignable to `Set<? extends Class<?>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You must consider '?' means 'Unknown', not 'any'.

```
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

subTypes is a set of Class 'unknown'. It could be String, Integer, List... any of them.

getSubTypesOf(type) will return a certain but unknown set of classes. I use 'certain' because we know all will extend the class of type. So it's not the same. The problem is it seems you don't know the class of type on compilation time.

`Set<Class>` should work too, but it will show a warning because you don't use the generic with Class.

Comment: Now I got it (at least partially :)). Looks like by saying _"'?' means 'Unknown', not 'any'"_, you exactly describe what's going on. Even if I think of `Class<?> type` parameter as of _any class_, the result of call to `getSubTypesOf` is not "any classes", but ones constrained by being subtypes of `type`, so it cannot look like `Class<?>` just in the same way as `type`. I wish however there were some pretty looking way to handle such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

As `?` is the wildcard, when you insert a `Class<?>`, the method returns a `Set<Class<? extends ?>>` (purely theoretical and not supported by Java) - try calling the method with a concrete type (e.g. `Class<Number>`) and you should get a `Set<Class<? extends Number>>` returned.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't know the concrete class of `type` parameter because it is read before from an annotation on another class, and is allowed to be of any type.

Comment: Then you have to add a type parameter to the method which calls the reflection call, that you have a `Class<T>` to call the reflection method with.

Answer (score 1):

The following will help: Your have `? extends T` (restricted by T) for `Class` in right side (`getSubTypesOf` returns it), so you need to extend it in left side too:

```
Class<? extends T> type;
Set<Class<? extends T>> subTypesOf = getSubTypesOf(type);
```

instead of:

```
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

Comment: That would mean he has to extend his own method by a type parameter - you otherwise can not write `Class<? extends T>` as a local variable type.

Comment: That means that in left side u can receive only `Class<T>` or `Class<child of T>`. T is for restriction from up. Method returns `Set<Class<? extends T>>` so your left side should be restricted by T too.

Comment: @Smutje `T` would be an actual class, for example `Set<Class<? extends Number>> subTypesOf = getSubTypesOf(Number.class);`

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan I see your point, you mean `? extends ? extends T` will reduce to `? extends T` this way. However this is the final code which is not to be parameterized by something more concrete than `?`. I am totally agnostic of what `T` can be, because it can be anything.

Comment: @PavelS, I don't understand what do you mean with `? extends ? extends T`, but when don't inherit from T you get type mismatch, and compiler says about it. Also take a look for more detailed descriptions, so if right size (the method) just use with `Set<Class<? extends T>>` where is the reason to not use? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan BTW, the solution you provide in your answer produces a compile error as well (I use a concrete type T for the example): `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Class<? extends capture#18-of ? extends T>> to Set<Class<? extends T>>`. I guess this is because the result of `getSubtypesOf` produces classes that are subtypes of `type` (which is subtype of T), but not _any_ classes which are subtypes of T.

Comment: How?? For example just change `T` by `Integer` and it works normal `static public Set<Class<? extends Integer>> getSubTypesOf(final Class<Integer> type) {}` and adding `Class<T> type = null;
        final Set<Class<? extends Integer>> subTypesOf = getSubTypesOf(type);` works normal.

It seams you did something not iususal.

Comment: Yes, it compiles successfully this way as you write. I just mean that in your original answer `type` is declared as `Class<? extends T>`, as well as result of `getSubTypesOf`. So it would be `Class<? extends Integer> type=null;` in your last example which does not compile.

Comment: Yes, make changing in my provided example is assume, that you need changes also in `getSubTypesOf`return type and parameter also. If you made different change, please provide all code to compare and anderstand which is the problem of comparing.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan, this is my code of your example (sorry if I misunderstood what you meant): `public static Set<Class<? extends Integer>> getSubTypesOf(final Class<Integer> type) {return null;}`. The caller: `Class<? extends Integer> type = null; final Set<Class<? extends Integer>> subTypesOf = getSubTypesOf(type);`.

Comment: @PavelS Now I see: You can the method to `getSubTypesOf(final Class<? extends Integer> type)` OR declare `type` as `Class<Integer>`. In both cases `type` left and right sides should be the same. Yes my last provided example, 55 min ago, has this problem. Before described changes fix it.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan OK, anyway I cannot change the `getSubTypesOf` method's signature, as it comes from a third party library. So making the left side in consistence with its return value was the original problem. See *Paul Bellora*'s answer where he shows how to form the left side type which will compile OK (however the logic is still vague to me). And thank you for you participation and interest!