# Why ListList<? super E> is List<? extends List<? super E>> but not List<List<? super E>>

Tags: java, generics, casting, wildcard, lower-bound

I have a generic interface `interface ListList<E> extends List<List<E>>`. For some reasons, I can't cast `ListList<? super T>` to `List<List<? super T>>`. Is there any way of doing it and why it doesn't work?

By this moment I've already tried the following:

1. Simple assignment, this way I've managed to assign `ListList<? super T>` to `List<? extends List<? super T>>` (1), but when I try to assign `ListList<? super T>` to `List<List<? super T>>` I get `Incompatible types` compile-time error (1.1).
2. Explicit type conversion, it doesn't work because of the same `Incompatible types` compile-time error (2).
3. Casting to raw type `ListList`, it works (3), but I don't like raw types.
4. Adding all elements from `ListList<? super T>` to `List<? extends List<? super T>>`, it works (4), but I need a more general solution which works not only with `ListList<E>`, but with any generic type.

Here is my code:

```
ListList<? super T> var = new ArrayListList<>();
List<? extends List<? super T>> work = var; // (1)
List<List<? super T>> notWork = var; // (1.1)
List<List<? super T>> explicit = (List<List<? super T>>) var; // (2)
List<List<? super T>> raw = (ListList) var; // (3)
List<List<? super T>> copy = new ArrayList<>(); // (4)
copy.addAll(var); // (4)
```

I've expected `ListList<? super T>` to be `List<List<? super T>>`, but it appeared to be `List<? extends List<? super T>>`. I need to know why it is and how I can cast it to `List<List<? super T>>` without raw types and copying of elements.

Comment: I can only get this to compile by changing all `? super T` to plain `T`.  The same errors recur if I change them to `? extends T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, it looks like these assignments should all succeed, but they don't because of the inner wildcard `? super T`.  If we remove those wildcards, then all the assignments compile.

```
public static <T> void test() {
    ListList<T> var = new ArrayListList<>();
    List<? extends List<T>> work = var; // Compiles
    List<List<T>> notWork = var; // Compiles
    List<List<T>> explicit = (List<List<T>>) var; // Compiles
    List<List<T>> raw = (ListList) var; // Compiles with warning
    List<List<T>> copy = new ArrayList<>(); // Compiles
    copy.addAll(var); // Compiles
}
```

I still get the unchecked conversion warning for (3), but they all still compile.

At first glance it looks like declaring the interface

```
ListList<E> extends List<List<E>>
```

makes a `ListList` equivalent to a `List` of `List`s.  However what you have done is take a nested type parameter and made it the main type parameter.  The reason that that makes a difference is [nested wildcards don't perform wildcard capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779752/double-wildcard-parameterization-nested-wildcards-with-java-generics).

A nested wildcard here means "a list of lists of *any* type matching the bound", but a main-level wildcard here means "a 'listlist' of a *specific yet unknown type* matching the bound".

One cannot add an object that is a supertype of the lower bound to a collection, because the type parameter -- a *specific yet unknown type* -- may be the actual bound.

```
List<? super Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<>();
test2.add(2);   // Compiles; can add 2 if type parameter is Integer, Number, or Object
test2.add((Number) 2);   // Error - Can't add Number to what could be Integer
test2.add(new Object()); // Error - Can't add Object to what could be Integer
```

Because Java's generics are invariant, the types must match exactly when type parameters are involved, so similar cases for `ListList` all fail to compile.

```
// My assumption of how your ArrayListList is defined.
class ArrayListList<E> extends ArrayList<List<E>> implements ListList<E> {}

ListList<? super Integer> llOfSuperI = new ArrayListList<>();
llOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());  // capture fails to match Integer
llOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Number>());   // capture fails to match Number
llOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Object>());   // capture fails to match Object
```

However, a `List` of `List` compiles with all 3 cases.

```
List<List<? super Integer>> lOfLOfSuperI = new ArrayList<>();
lOfLOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());  // no capture; compiles
lOfLOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Number>());   // no capture; compiles
lOfLOfSuperI.add(new ArrayList<Object>());   // no capture; compiles
```

Your `ListList` is a different type than a `List` of `List`s, but the differing generics behavior of where the type parameter is defined means that there is different generics behavior.  This is why you cannot directly assign a `ListList<? super T>` to a `List<List<? super T>>` (1.1), and also why you can't cast it (2).  You can cast to a raw type to get it to compile (3), but that introduces the possibilities of `ClassCastException` in future use of the casted object; that is what the warning is about.  You can assign it to a `List<? extends List<? super T>>` (1), introducing another wildcard to capture a subtype relationship, but that introduces a wildcard to be captured; you won't be able to add anything useful to that list.

These differences have arisen only because a wildcard introduces wildcard capture and the associated differences.  Without using a wildcard, a `ListList<E>` is equivalent to a `List<List<E>>` and as shown at the top of this answer, shows no problems compiling the code.

If you want all of your sub-lists to use the same exact type parameter, then go ahead and use your `ListList` interface, but don't use any wildcards.  This forces the exact same type parameter for all lists that are added to your `ListList`, i.e. a `ListList<Integer>` can only hold `List<Integer>`s.

If you want all of your sub-lists to simply match a wildcard, e.g. contain a `List<Number>`, `List<Integer>`, and `List<Object>` in the same list, then just use a `List<List<? super T>>` to avoid wildcard capture.