# Nested generic and wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I have some generic code:

```
T1<T1<T1<?>>> v1 = null;
T1<T1<?>> v2 = v1;
```

for which I get this error:

```
incompatible types: T1<T1<T1<?>>> cannot be converted to T1<T1<?>>
```

Why can't I assign here?

In case of non-nested wildcard all works fine:

```
    T1<T1<?>> v1 = null;
    T1<?> v2 = v1;
```

Do not have such problem.

Definition of `T1`

```
class T1<T> { }
```

Comment: What is the real problem you intend to solve by creating a 3 level nesting like that?

Comment: It is simplified example. In real app I have different classes on each level, some of them have more than one generic parameter.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a nice duplicated question for your request, but alas, I can't find it right now ;-)

Comment: Something like this comes pretty close to what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766704 But technically this is also a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265 Long story short: you'd need `T1<? extends T1<?>> v2 = v1;`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign this because `T1<T1<T1<?>>>` is not an instance of `T1<T1<?>>`.

Why? Let's analyze this:

- `T1<T1<T1<?>>>`: an instance of `T1` whose type parameter is exactly `T1<T1<?>>`
- `T1<T1<?>>`: an instance of `T1` whose type parameter is exactly `T1<?>`

So you cannot assign because type parameter `T1<?>` is not exactly the same as type parameter `T1<T1<?>>`.

As John Vernee pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837881/nested-generic-and-wildcard#comment90629441_51837881), you'd need `T1<? extends T1<?>>` for this to work because:

- `T1<? extends T1<?>>`: an instance of `T1` whose type parameter is `T1<?>` or its subtype (like `T1<T1<?>>`)

---

*EDIT*: Why can you assign `T1<T1<?>>` (or even `T1<T1<T1<?>>`) to `T1<?>`? Because:

- `T1<?>`: an instance of `T1` whose type parameter can by *anything*

---

To take it even further: `T1<T1<T1<T1<?>>>` could be assigned to the following types having fewer `T1`s:

- `T1<? extends T1<? extends T1<?>>`
- `T1<? extends T1<?>`
- `T1<?>`
- `Object` (which corresponds to pure `?`)

I hope it's clear now how this nested generic subclassing works.

PS. Follow a link in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405866/java-nested-wildcard-generic-wont-compile#comment43309577_3405866), where wildcard nesting is explained in more detail.

Comment: Based on this logic my second example shouldn't work too, because `T1<?>1 is not exactly `?`, but it works fine.

Comment: @talex See my edit. I hope it'll clarify things for you.